# symfony make:entity crash on new project

Tags: php, symfony, console, entity

Whenever I try to create an entity with bin/console make:entity, I get the following result:

```
php bin/console make:entity

 Class name of the entity to create or update (e.g. FierceElephant):
 > Video


In DebugClassLoader.php line 337:

  Warning: include(/home/user/work/project1/vendor/composer/../../src/Entity/Video.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory
```

This project is very new and there is very few code at the moment; It's the first entity I try to create in the project. I don't get why I get this since it's obvious that the file does not exist since I want to create it... 
I haven't found similar problem on google. Maybe I forgot to activate a php extension?

Any idea?

Comment: Could be directory permissions and it can't write the file, so it's failing silently then when it tries to open it it doesn't exist. Seems like it would throw an error for failing to create but I don't have the code infront of me to check

Comment: didn't think of that, but I've checked and everything is with the same user I'm using, and in 775 so I guess the reason is elsewhere...

Comment: Does the /home/user/work/project1/src/Entity directory exists?

Comment: Tried with sudo ?

Comment: Try composer install (reinstall)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Might need to composer dump-autoload if you've messed up and removed some classes by hand.